How to update invoice status in a test class with regards to financial force
I am trying to write a test class for a batch apex and its failing because I cant update my invoices to use to run the rest of the test class data.
The invoices are from financial force and when I try to update them in the test I get a custom validation exception
@isTest
public with sharing class ServicesBatchTest {

    @testSetup
    static void setupTestData() {
        // Insert test group (queue)
        Group testGroup = new Group(Name = 'test group', Type = 'Queue');
        insert testGroup;

        System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())) {
            List<QueueSObject> listQueue = new List<QueueSObject>();

            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'Case'));
            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c'));
            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c'));
            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'c2g__codaCompany__c'));
            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'c2g__codaYear__c'));
            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'c2g__codaInvoice__c'));
            listQueue.add(new QueueSObject(QueueId = testGroup.Id, SObjectType = 'c2g__codaCreditNote__c'));

            insert listQueue;

            GroupMember groupMember = new GroupMember();
            groupMember.GroupId = testGroup.Id;
            groupMember.UserOrGroupId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            insert groupMember;
        }

        // Create other required test data
        Account account = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            c2g__CODAAccountTradingCurrency__c = 'USD',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert account;

        Product2 product = new Product2(
            Name = 'TestProduct',
            Item_Type__c = 'Product',
            Description = 'description',
            Create_Asset__c = 'No',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
            Zeus_ScanTypeID__c = '11',
            Technician_Product_ID__c = '11',
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert product;

        Product2 product2 = new Product2(
            Name = 'Remote Discount',
            Item_Type__c = 'Product',
            Description = 'description',
            Create_Asset__c = 'No',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
            Zeus_ScanTypeID__c = '123',
            Technician_Product_ID__c = '123',
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert product2;

        c2g__codaCompany__c company = new c2g__codaCompany__c(
            Name = 'Repairify, Inc. DBA asTech',
            c2g__CashMatchingCurrencyMode__c = 'Test Account',
            c2g__YearEndMode__c = 'Full Accounting Code',
            c2g__ExternalId__c = 'ABCDE1234567876',
            c2g__LogoURL__c = 'www.XYZ.com',
            c2g__ECCountryCode__c = 'AE',
            c2g__VATRegistrationNumber__c = 'Test 222.222.222 TVA',
            c2g__Website__c = 'www.xyz.com',
            c2g__Country__c = 'US',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
            Order__c = 10.5,
            c2g__ExternalTaxCalculation__c = 'Disabled',
            OwnerId = testGroup.Id
        );
        insert company;

        c2g__codaUserCompany__c userCompany = new c2g__codaUserCompany__c(
            c2g__Company__c = company.Id,
            c2g__User__c = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            c2g__ExternalId__c = 'ABCDE1234567876',
            c2g__UnitOfWork__c = 111
        );
        insert userCompany;

        c2g__codaYear__c year = new c2g__codaYear__c(
            Name = '2015',
            c2g__AutomaticPeriodList__c = true,
            c2g__ExternalId__c = 'qwer321',
            c2g__Status__c = 'Open',
            c2g__YearEndMode__c = 'Full Accounting Code',
            c2g__UnitOfWork__c = 12,
            c2g__NumberOfPeriods__c = 11,
            c2g__PeriodCalculationBasis__c = '445',
            c2g__StartDate__c = (System.today() - 10),
            c2g__OwnerCompany__c = company.Id,
            OwnerId = testGroup.Id
        );
        insert year;

        c2g__codaPeriod__c period = new c2g__codaPeriod__c(
            c2g__StartDate__c = (System.today() - 10),
            c2g__EndDate__c = (System.today() + 10),
            c2g__OwnerCompany__c = company.Id,
            c2g__PeriodNumber__c = '123',
            c2g__YearName__c = year.Id
        );
        insert period;

        c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c accountingCurrency = new c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c(
            c2g__OwnerCompany__c = company.Id,
            c2g__DecimalPlaces__c = 2,
            Name = 'USD',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'
        );
        insert accountingCurrency;

        List<c2g__codaInvoice__c> invoices = new List<c2g__codaInvoice__c>{
            new c2g__codaInvoice__c(
                Work_Order_Number__c = '1236',
                zeus_InvoiceId__c = '12345',
                CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
                zeus_Inv_Seq__c = '1',
                RO_Number__c = 'RO Number',
                c2g__InvoiceStatus__c = 'In Progress',
                VIN__c = 'vin',
                Vehicle_Year__c = '2022',
                Vehicle_Make__c = 'BMW',
                Vehicle_Model__c = 'X4',
                c2g__Account__c = account.Id,
                Insurance__c = 'AAA',
                Credited__c = false
            ),
            new c2g__codaInvoice__c(
                Work_Order_Number__c = '1237',
                zeus_InvoiceId__c = '12346',
                CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
                zeus_Inv_Seq__c = '2',
                RO_Number__c = 'RO Number 2',
                c2g__InvoiceStatus__c = 'In Progress',
                VIN__c = 'vin2',
                Vehicle_Year__c = '2023',
                Vehicle_Make__c = 'Audi',
                Vehicle_Model__c = 'Q5',
                c2g__Account__c = account.Id,
                Insurance__c = 'BBB',
                Credited__c = false
            )
        };
        insert invoices;

        // Update invoices to 'Complete'
       
      
        for (c2g__codaInvoice__c invoice : invoices) {
            invoice.c2g__InvoiceStatus__c = 'Complete';
        }
        update invoices;
         System.debug(invoices);
    }

    @isTest
    static void testBatchExecution() {
        // Run the batch job
        Test.startTest();
        ServicesBatch batch = new ServicesBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Retrieve the invoices again to check their lastModifiedDate
        List<c2g__codaInvoice__c> invoices = [SELECT Id, c2g__Account__c, lastModifiedDate FROM c2g__codaInvoice__c WHERE c2g__InvoiceStatus__c = 'Complete'];

        // Map to hold the latest invoice date for each account
        Map<Id, Date> accountInvoiceMap = new Map<Id, Date>();

        // Iterate through the invoices to get the latest modified date for each account
        for (c2g__codaInvoice__c invoice : invoices) {
            Date invoiceDate = invoice.lastModifiedDate.date();
            if (!accountInvoiceMap.containsKey(invoice.c2g__Account__c) || invoiceDate > accountInvoiceMap.get(invoice.c2g__Account__c)) {
                accountInvoiceMap.put(invoice.c2g__Account__c, invoiceDate);
            }
        }

        // Verify the latest invoice date for the account is correctly updated
        Account updatedAccount = [SELECT Id, Last_Invoice_Date__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account' LIMIT 1];

        System.assertEquals(accountInvoiceMap.get(updatedAccount.Id), updatedAccount.Last_Invoice_Date__c);
    }

    @isTest
    static void testSchedulableExecution() {
        // Schedule the batch job
        String cronExp = '0 0 0 15 6 ? 2024';
        ServicesBatch schedulableBatch = new ServicesBatch();
        String jobId = System.schedule('Test Scheduled Batch', cronExp, schedulableBatch);

        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :jobId];
        System.assertEquals(cronExp, ct.CronExpression);
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
    }
}

I did try using seealldata equals true but while the test works on my sandbox. I have issues deploying it to production so I am trying to create the data in the test
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class ServicesBatchTest {
 

   @IsTest
    static void testExecute() {
        // Fetch a small set of existing invoices to use in the test
        Test.startTest();
        List<c2g__codaInvoice__c> testInvoices = [SELECT Id, c2g__Account__c, c2g__InvoiceStatus__c, LastModifiedDate 
                                                  FROM c2g__codaInvoice__c 
                                                  WHERE c2g__InvoiceStatus__c = 'Complete' 
                                                  AND LastModifiedDate = TODAY
                                                  LIMIT 5];
        
        // Ensure there is at least one invoice to test
        if (testInvoices.isEmpty()) {
            System.debug('No invoices found with the status Complete and modified today.');
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of the batch class and call the execute method directly
        
        ServicesBatch batch = new ServicesBatch();  
        Database.executeBatch(batch, 5);  
        Test.stopTest();


        // Verify the results
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (c2g__codaInvoice__c invoice : testInvoices) {
            if (invoice.c2g__Account__c != null) {
                accountIds.add(invoice.c2g__Account__c);
            }
        }

        List<Account> updatedAccounts = [SELECT Id, Last_Invoice_Date__c 
                                         FROM Account 
                                         WHERE Id IN :accountIds 
                                         AND Last_Invoice_Date__c != NULL];

        System.assert(!updatedAccounts.isEmpty(), 'Accounts should have been updated with the latest invoice date');

        // Additional assertions to check specific business logic if required
        for (Account acc : updatedAccounts) {
            Date latestInvoiceDate = null;
            for (c2g__codaInvoice__c invoice : testInvoices) {
                if (invoice.c2g__Account__c == acc.Id) {
                    Date invoiceDate = invoice.LastModifiedDate.date();
                    if (latestInvoiceDate == null || invoiceDate > latestInvoiceDate) {
                        latestInvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.assertEquals(latestInvoiceDate, acc.Last_Invoice_Date__c, 'The Last_Invoice_Date__c should match the latest invoice date for the account.');
        }
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testSchedulable() {
        // Execute the scheduled job
     
        Test.startTest();
        ServicesBatch schedulable = new ServicesBatch();
        String jobId = System.schedule('TestScheduledBatch', '0 0 0 * * ?', schedulable);
        schedulable.execute(null);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Verify that the job has been scheduled
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :jobId];
        System.assertEquals('0 0 0 * * ?', ct.CronExpression);
        System.assert(ct.NextFireTime != null, 'Scheduled job should have a next fire time');
    }
}


Has anyone dealt with financial force with regards to updating invoices in test classes. I would really appreciate some pointers.
Thank you.

You'll have to contact Certinia support.
